# IIS 8.5 returns old version of a file from a virtual directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpresponse, virtual-directory

I have a file in a virtual directory `myfile.html`. After I change the file content, some times I receive an old file version, maybe some caching is there but I don't understand where, below is my rewrite:

```
protected void Rewrite(HttpRequest request, HttpApplication httpApp)
{
    Uri uri = request.Url;
    if (uri == null)
    {
        return;
    }
    httpApp.Context.Response.Cache.SetNoServerCaching();
    httpApp.Context.RewritePath("PathFromVirtualDirectory/myfile.html", true);
}
```

In my `web.config` I have a few settings to disabling caching.

```xml
<staticContent>
    <clientCache cacheControlMode="DisableCache"/>
</staticContent>
<!-- additional settings -->
<caching>
    <profiles>
        <add extension="*" policy="DontCache" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange"/>
    </profiles>
</caching>
```

The file on the server is changed, but the get request returns old version of the file.

Comment: Have you tried to add querytring to url? for example http://myserver.com/PathFromVirtualDirectory/myfile.html?version=1

Comment: @Manfred Radlwimmer, yes using new Random(), nothing changes

Comment: @Alex I think you `@`-ed the wrong person.